# Clearing keyboard buffer correctly

Tags: c

I'm trying to do a problem for my computing class and i'm having trouble. The problem is a ferry that is l length needs to carry cars l length from the left side of the river to the right, i'm sure someone has heard of it before. My only problem (i have a good idea how to do most of the code, just hit a snag) is that I'm either stuck in an infinite loop, or my nested loop exits the for loop it's nested in near the very bottom. My code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
int testCases;
int ferrySize;
int numOfCars;
char riverSide; // what side of river is the car on?
char c; // eats unnecessary characters
int test=1;
int i,j=0;// counters for "for" and "while" loops
int carLength;
const int cm_to_m=100;

printf("How many tests would you like to have?: ");
scanf("%d", &testCases);
printf("how long is the ferry in meters and how many cars are there?: ");
scanf("%d", &ferrySize);
ferrySize=ferrySize*cm_to_m;
scanf("%d", &numOfCars);
printf("cases %d ferrysize %d cars %d\n", testCases, ferrySize, numOfCars);
printf("\nhow long is each car (in cm) and what side is it on?\n(seperate this info with a space)\nseperate each car by new lines.");


for(i=0; i<=numOfCars;i++);
{
    scanf("%d", &carLength);
    scanf(" %c", &riverSide);
    printf("%c", riverSide);
    do
    {
        scanf("%c", &c);
        printf("%c", c);
    }while(c!='t' && c!='T');
    printf("%c", riverSide);

}
return 0;
```

}

Comment: For scanning characters, use `getchar()` instead of `scanf("%c",...)`. `scanf()` is poor at scanning characters.

Comment: My professor for some reason taught us to use scanf instead. i think he wants us to ignore whitespace characters for some reason? also, i tried the getchar function just incase it would fix it- it had the same effect as scanf. exiting the program (though not with a crash) as if it were done running everything, though the for loop was still supposed to run.

Comment: Can you give a sample input and expected output?

Comment: input:
testCases: 2
ferrysize: 20
numOfCars: 3
(entering loop)
1st car:
carLength:20
riverSide: l (left, only the l is needed to indicate it though)
the scanf in the do[]while() loop empties keyboard buffer,
car 2: 30 : riverSide: r(right, r again is all that's needed.)
the do while loop once again clears the buffer, THIS time it ends the loop. usually it exits the for loop after the first loop even though it shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

Try using fflush(), it will empty the buffer and the code will run just fine.

Comment: Would the file for the buffer be stdin? I'll try it. Thanks

Comment: If you don't give it any parameter it will flush everything. Give it a try that way.

Comment: It still exits all loops. i'm going to guess something's wrong with my for loop... Edit: i found the problem! it was with my for loop, check the condition... for(...;...;...); instead of for(...;...;...)

Comment: I checked your code. I don't really see the point of it, but obviously you should remove the semicolon after the for cycle:
So instead of for(i=0; i<=numOfCars;i++); {...
You should use for(i=0; i<=numOfCars;i++) {...

Answer (score 0):

Check the extra semicolon at the end of your for loop line.  You could also do the following in the loop to read the values (ignoring safety, etc.):

```
for(i=0; i<numOfCars; i++) {
    scanf("%d %c", &carLength, &riverSide);
    printf("car is %d long and on the %c side\n", carLength, riverSide");
}
```